# How to fix: coreml models from coremltools conversion of multiclass xgboost model producing seemingly random output, with python 3.7?

Tags: python, xgboost, coreml, coremltools

When converting a multiclass softmax Xgboost model using the coremltools convert function, it results in a mlmodel that gives predictions in no particular range and the output values are not comparable to the output of the xgboost model.

This is for creating a CoreML model that can be implemented in an iOS application for real life sensor data classification. I have tried all kinds of possibilities within the convert function itself.

Here is the setup for the Xgboost model:

```py
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(fft_train, label=l_train)
deval = xgb.DMatrix(fft_val, label=l_val)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(fft_test)
evallist = [(dtrain, 'train'), (deval, 'eval')]

param = {'eta': eta, 'objective': 'multi:softprob', 'num_class': 11, 'eval_metric': 'mlogloss', 'subsample': subsample, 'max_depth': max_depth, 'gamma': gamma}

evals_result = {}
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, evallist, early_stopping_rounds=3, evals_result=evals_result, verbose_eval=10)
```

Here is the conversion:

```py
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.xgboost.convert(bst, feature_names = feature_names, target = target, mode = 'classifier', n_classes = 11)
coreml_model.save('Name_of_model.mlmodel')
```

The results that are expected from the converted CoreML model are in the range from 0 to 1, but the actual output are seemingly random floats, negative and positive. There is also no correlation between the actual output and expected output.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the inputs you're giving the Core ML model are in the expected range for the model? It's easy to make a mistake in the `MLMultiArray`.

Comment: I am pretty sure, but have not double or triple checked it. Maybe that is something good to check out again. I think it shouldn't be different, as I used the same data for the CoreML implementation and the XGBoost model implementation, and only the CoreML model creates those problems.